# Выполнение одинаковых действий нажатием разных кнопок

Tags: javascript, java, любой-язык, соревнование

К примеру у меня есть несколько кнопок, в одной из них по нажатию я пишу выполнение какого-либо действий, например отобразить текст кнопки в лейбле. 
Возникает необходимость, чтобы по нажатию другой кнопки делалось точно такое же действие что и по нажатию первой кнопки. Я же не буду копировать весь код вручную... Думаю что можно как-то вызвать действие во второй кнопке из первой? Подскажите как это делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для языков с ООП можно по разному. Например, так:

1. Создайте метод, выполняющий действия, которые должны произойти по нажатию. Назначьте каждой кнопке слушатель нажатий и вызовите там этот метод.
2. Создайте отдельный класс, реализующий интерфейс слушателя нажатия на кнопку. Передавайте его экземпляр в метод назначения слушателя.
3. Если всем кнопкам слушатель назначается в одном классе, то заставьте этот класс реализовать интерфей слушателя и передавайте в назначатель слушателя сей класс, т.е. `this`

Comment: Мне кажется, что он не осилит Ваш ответ. Судя по вопросу он новичок и если бы понимал о чем Вы пишите, то не задавал бы таких вопросов.

Comment: Первый пункт мне понятен, буду пробовать. Спасибо ;)

Comment: Мой пример конечно не с просто двумя кнопками, чуть сложнее(пытаюсь переделать виндовый блокнот), но с вашей помощью в одном из вопросов разобрался:) Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Набрасал пример.
Здесь мы добавляем обработчик события на все элементы с классом `buttons` в `div`, и на те которые присутствуют, и на те которые появятся в дальнейшем.
Если Ваши кнопки не добавляются динамически, то строку
`$("div").on("click", ".buttons", function(e) { ... });`
необходимо заменить на
`$("div .buttons").on("click", function(e) { ... });`

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".buttons", function(e) {
  $("textarea").append($.trim($(e.target).text()) + ", ");
});

$("#addButton").on("click", function(e) {
  var num = $("#container .buttons").length + 1;
  var $button = $("#container .buttons:first").clone().html("Button " + num).appendTo("div");
});
```

```css
div,
p {
  margin: 5px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 3</button>
</div>
<p>
  <button id="addButton">Add button</button>
</p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

[Пример на JSFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/p6co6fbu/)

Comment: Наглядный пример, но вопрос, вроде, по Яве)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот это я облажался :(

Comment: А мы щас лёгким движением превратим ошибку в... не ошибку. Следите за метками вопроса)